# Angular 5 ngFor close tag after specific repeat

Tags: angular, angular5

In angular 5 template I have markup like this

```
<section class="tickets-block">
    <div class="container small">
        <div class="our-team">
            <ul>
                <li class="custom" *ngFor="let event of events; let i=index">
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

In the li tag you can see I have used ngFor loop. So basically I want that after 3 li the ul tag should automatically close and after that it should again start the ul with li tag.

So my output should look like this

```
<section class="tickets-block">
    <div class="container small">
        <div class="our-team">
            <ul>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <section class="tickets-block">
    <div class="container small">
        <div class="our-team">
            <ul>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
                <li class="custom>
                {{event.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

So can someone tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Comment: `<li class="custom>` where is closing double quotes ?

Comment: The HTML output looks a bit messed up... are you looking to nest the second set of `<ul>` or is it  typo?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert array to multidemensional array like

```
events = [ [{...},{...}, {...}], [{...},{...}, {...}] ]
```

and in html:

```
<ul *ngFor="let row of events">
  <li *ngFor="let event of row">{{ event.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Also you can use hack like this in your html

```
  <ul *ngFor="let row of events.slice(0, events.length/3 + 1); let i = index">
    <li *ngFor="let event of events.slice(i * 3, i * 3 + 3)">{{ event.name }}</li>
  </ul>
```